# Mapserver/PostGIS FILTER Query Error

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I am new using mapsever. I downloaded an example from Internet (http://www.codegeo.com.br/search/label/MapServer). I tested it in my PC, my development environment (mapserver version 6.4.1), and it works.

Now I put it in a "testing enviroment" (mapserver version 7.0.0), but I have a problem with the FILTER directive in the mapfile.

This is the code in the .map file:

`DATA "the_geom FROM estados USING UNIQUE id USING SRID=4326"`
`FILTER "sigla ILIKE '%%state%%'"`

When I execute the script, I get an empty png file but there is no errors:

`$ mapserv -nh "QUERY_STRING=map=/var/www/codegeo/codegeo.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=states&estado=SP&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A900913&STYLES=&BBOX=0%2C0%2C2504688.5428486555%2C2504688.5428486555"`

The log file defined into the mapfile file has the following error:

`executing query: select "nome","codigo",encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force2D("the_geom"),'NDR'),'hex') as geom,"id" from estados where the_geom && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0.0439453124999988 0.0439453081913454,0.0439453124999988 21.9022779666686,22.4560546875 21.9022779666686,22.4560546875 0.0439453081913454,0.0439453124999988 0.0439453081913454))',4326) and ()
[Mon Feb 27 11:39:06 2017].147993 msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error executing query. Check server logs
[Mon Feb 27 12:05:49 2017].361015 getSymbol(): Symbol definition error. Parsing error near (():(line 123)
[Mon Feb 27 11:39:06 2017].147993 msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error executing query. Check server logs
[Mon Feb 27 12:05:49 2017].361015 getSymbol(): Symbol definition error. Parsing error near (():(line 123)`

I know that is something wrong with the filter instruction. If i comment it , I see the layer in the web page. I didn't find any documentation about ILIKE operator.

Somebody knows which is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

From Mapserver 7, you cannot use "native filters" anymore.

Check the docs here
http://mapserver.org/de/mapfile/layer.html (under FILTER).

You need to rewrite the filter using the expression syntax documented here http://mapserver.org/de/mapfile/expressions.html#expressions